# Commerce checkout does not work when loading from AJAX

Tags: ajax, commerce

In D7, I have a dropdown form field that has an #ajax attribute pointing to a callback function that triggers when the drop down value is selected. In the callback function, I load the current Commerce order and then the Commerce checkout form using:

```
$commerce_form = commerce_checkout_router($order);
```

I then render the checkout form and display in the template:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_html('#checkout-section', '');
$commands[] = ajax_command_append('#checkout-section', render($commerce_form));

return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

When I do that, it looks like my checkout form does not get properly bootstraped and I lose all the interactivity of the checkout form I've set up using hook_info's etc.

When I visit the checkout form without AJAX everything works well.

Do I need to somehow bootstrap Drupal Commerce inside AJAX callbacks if I want to use AJAX so all my hooks that customize the Commerce Checkout?

PS: I am doing a

```
require_once '../contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/includes/commerce_checkout.pages.inc';
```

inside the callback. Without this I get functions not defined errors on core Commerce functions. (The Drupal Commerce and all related modules are enabled and it only happens in the AJAX callbacks.)

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same Problem, i think this page should help you: [Loading a form by ajax](https://www.drupal.org/node/2009252).

I have solved this problem, but I think its a little bit ugly. The Problem was that I have loaded the checkout form, but not the scripts which are necessary on the checkout page. So i have loaded the scripts from the checkout page, too. After that i have done a

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

So all scripts can attach there functionality to the checkout form.

Comment: Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.